# How to update VSCode in goDevBox [alpha]

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

New version of VSCode was released, so I want to update it on my instance of [goDevBox](https://godevbox.com/)

I can try doing it from integrated terminal from VSCode itself, but I am not sure that it is a correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code-server part can be upgraded by running the following command:

```sh
sudo curl -fsSL https://code-server.dev/install.sh | sh
```

Here there are more info from the official repo:
https://github.com/cdr/code-server/blob/main/docs/install.md#upgrading

After this command, I suggest forcing a machine reboot in order to have the new version kicking in.

```sh
sudo reboot
```